# React Redux: Can't map over state after using combineReducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to React/Redux.

I'm making simple shopping cart. 
Right now I'm trying to display data from local json file. 
The data is in state like: {items: *data here* }. 
I can map over this items when I write reducer on the top level reducer file. 
However if I use combineReducers it will give me error saying "this.props.items is undefined: return this.props.items.slice(0, 20).map(item => ".

How do I access and map over the items?

#### Reducer #1 `cartReducer.js`

```js
import data from "../data.json";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    items: data,
    addedItem: [],
    total: 0
}

const cartReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    return state;
}

export default cartReducer;
```

#### Reducer #2

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import items from './cartReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    items
})
```

#### Component to display items list

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addToCart } from '../actions';

class ItemList extends React.Component {

    renderList() {
      return this.props.items.slice(0, 20).map(item => {
        return (
          <div className="card" key={item.id}>
                <span className="card-title">{item.name}</span>                
                <p>{item.content}</p>
                <p><b>Price: {item.price}$</b></p>    
          </div>
        )
      })      
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
             {this.renderList()}
           </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    items: state.items
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    addToCart: (id) => {
      dispatch(addToCart(id))
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ItemList);
```

#### JSON data

```
[
  {
      "id": 201,
      "name": "Nulla",
      "price": 207,
      "subCategoryId": 101,
      "categoryId": 1,
      "rate": 2.44,
      "content": "Culpa sed tenetur incidunt quia veniam sed mollitia exercitationem. Laboriosam reprehenderit laborum pariatur ea rem qui inventore. In asperiores dignissimos temporibus et. Beatae consequatur corrupti nam praesentium.",
      "review": 78,
      "typeVariant": "D",
      "colorVariant": "5",
      "imageUrl": "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=55&txt=137x945&w=137&h=945"
    },{
      "id": 202,
      "name": "Corporis",
      "price": 271,
      "subCategoryId": 101,
      "categoryId": 1,
      "rate": 2.18,
      "content": "Nam incidunt blanditiis odio inventore. Nobis voluptatum quibusdam laboriosam a numquam. Delectus sequi ipsa possimus ratione repellendus quibusdam. Molestiae fuga laudantium natus dolorem.",
      "review": 67,
      "typeVariant": "A",
      "colorVariant": "4",
      "imageUrl": "https://dummyimage.com/931x785"
    }
]
```

Comment: Try `debugger` or `console.log(this.props)` as the first line in the render method. Seems that that your component has not received the expected props.

Comment: When I did `console.log(this.props)` it gave me an object containing each state, which was not able to map over. In order to use map, state seems to have to look like `return { items: state.items.items }`. That will give me an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a reducer using `combineReducers` you create a reducer that will call each reducer passed to it, gathering their result into a new state object. The key for each reducers state will be the key that you gave the respective reducer in the object you passed to `combineReducers`.

If you use only your reducer, your resulting state would be as you expected:

```
{
    items: Array
    addedItem: Array
    total: number
}
```

```js
export default combineReducers({
    items
})
```

Is syntactic sugar for

```js
export default combineReducers({
    items: items
})
```

Which means that the final state will look something like this:

```
{
    items: {
        items: Array
        addedItem: Array
        total: number
    }
}
```

As such, you can access the `items` array in your state using `state.items.items`

Comment: This is true, but the error says that `this.props.items` is undefined, so there's something else wrong as well, it seems.

Comment: `this.props.items` is undefined because OP maps `state.items` to `items`. Instead of the correct `state.items.items`.

Comment: you can add condition before rendering this.props.items &&

Comment: If `state.items` is undefined, you can't access `state.items.items` either. It might be that redux has not been initialized properly.

Comment: I changed to return `{ items: state.items.items }` and it worked. Now I understand how the sugar syntactic. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You don't bind renderList and that's why props is undefined. "This" refers to the calling function (renderList) and not your component. And the function does not have a field props because it is just a function. You have to bind it within the constructor like this: this.renderList= this.renderList.bind(this); or use a array function like this: const renderList = () => {...}. Now "this" refers to the component and props will be defined.

Comment: And of course what @Phillip said it crucial as well.

Answer (score -1):

you have to pass type in dispatch

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    addToCart: id => {
      dispatch({ type: 'name of your type' });
    }
  };
};
```

and then add condition to your reducer

```
const cartReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
   if(action.type === 'name of your type')
      return state;
}
```

Comment: It looks like OP is using action creators. Anyway this is definitely not the issue